# How to map coords (x,y) to a H-tree?

Tags: fractals

For a mini game I want to have a map resembling the [H-Tree Fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_tree). The line would be road and you can drive around but only on the road. The map is infinite and needs to be generated as you drive around.

So given a coordinate (x,y) how do I decide if it's road or not road?

Lets define some constants:

The length of each cul-de-sac is L.
The line segments in each iteration grow by a factor of 1.5, no sqrt(2), to keep everything rational.
And a road is any point at a distance <= 1 from the line. max(dx, dy) <= 1 if that is simpler.

The start point is (0,0) and can be any cul-de-sac on the H-tree, your choice.

Comment: You should probably construct a signed distance field and check if the distance is less than 0, but I don't know enough to construct it. Maybe I will try tomorrow.

Comment: The problem I see is mapping 2D coords into some coordinate system of the H-tree that lets me know where in tree I am. Like with a siepinsky carpet you convert to base 3 numbers and then you can tell if you are in a hole.

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot]

Signed distance field implemented in Shader Editor for Android from f-Droid:

```
#version 300 es
#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
precision highp float;
#else
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 resolution;

out vec4 outColour;

void main(void)
{
  // p determined by pixel coordinates
  vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy - resolution.xy * 0.5;
  p /= 8.0;
  float dL = length(vec4(dFdx(p), dFdy(p)));
  // signed distance to road
  float z = 1.0/0.0;
  // road width (not cul-de-sac length)
  float L = 0.1;
  // inflation factor
  float f = sqrt(2.0);
  // transformation
  mat2 m = mat2(0, 1, -1, 0) * f;
  mat2 m1 = inverse(m);
  vec2 c = vec2(1.0, 0.0);
  // inverse transform to base region
  int maxd = 24; // determines maximum extent
  int D = 0; // count steps
  float fd = 1.0; // for uniform road width
  for (int d = 0; d < maxd; ++d)
  {
    if (abs(p.x) < 1.0 && abs(p.y) < f)
    {
      D = d + 1;
      break;
    }
    p = m1 * (p - c);
    fd /= f;
  }
  // finite tree
  if (D == 0)
  {
    outColour = vec4(1,0,0,1);
    return;
  }
  // add detail
  for (int d = 0; d < D; ++d)
  {
    // two line segments / rectangles
    z = min(z, min(max(abs(p.x/fd) - L, abs(p.y/fd) - 1.0/f/fd),
      max(max(-L - p.x/fd, p.x/fd - (1.0/fd + L)), abs(p.y/fd) - L)));
    // transformation, note abs for symmetry
    p = m * abs(p) + c;
    fd *= f;
  }
  // colouring according to distance: z < 0 means road (white)
  outColour = vec4(vec3(1.0 - smoothstep(max(z, 0.0), 0.0, 0.5*dL)), 1.0);
}
```

This is using single precision floating point with an approximate $\sqrt{2}$.
Other inflation factors don't look so good.

The shader code uses a fixed maximum iteration count because unbounded loops on a GPU can be problematic. Moreover with floating point, rounding errors may accumulate.  With exact arithmetic and enough memory, this limit can be increased (each increment of 1 doubles the area covered by the tree) or even removed (risking memory exhaustion from large integer storage at extreme distances from the origin).

There is a way to do exact arithmetic with numbers like $a + b \sqrt{2} \quad a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$:

$$(a + b \sqrt{2}) + (x + y \sqrt{2}) = (a + x) + (b + y) \sqrt{2}$$
$$(a + b \sqrt{2}) - (x + y \sqrt{2}) = (a - x) + (b - y) \sqrt{2}$$
$$(a + b \sqrt{2})   (x + y \sqrt{2}) = (a x + 2 b y) + (a y + b x) \sqrt{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{a + b \sqrt{2}} = \frac{a}{d} - \frac{b}{d} \sqrt{2} \text{ where } d = a^2 - 2 b^2$$
$$a + b \sqrt{2} > 0 \text{ when } a > 0 \wedge b > 0$$
$$a + b \sqrt{2} < 0 \text { when } a < 0 \wedge b < 0$$
$$a + b \sqrt{2} > 0 \equiv a^2 > 2 b^2 \text{ when } a > 0 \wedge b < 0 $$
$$a + b \sqrt{2} > 0 \equiv a^2 < 2 b^2 \text{ when } a < 0 \wedge b > 0 $$

You don't need to evaluate or store the $\sqrt{2}$, it's symbolic.

Make sure to use unbounded integers for the rational numbers (overflow of fixed size integral types is catastrophic here).

Comment: Could you explain the code a bit more? The first loop looks like you fold the coordinates across the trees similarity. The second than unfolds it again but with `abs(p)` mixed in so it always mirrored on the positive side. The `z` calculation seems to have no place inside the loop, only the last value is used. And it's limited to `maxd = 24` iteration. So it's a finite tree.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I updated the post with a bit more about the limit. Code is adjusted also: it breaks out of the loop as early as possible and handles the too-far case explicitly.  The `z` calculation is to find the minimum distance to all the roads at each level of the tree.  With the modifications there is a thinner road spiral artifact heading to the origin that I have not yet worked out how to eliminate.